# Flutter audioplayers FileNotFoundException: assets/audio/test.mp3

Tags: flutter

First of all, yes I've searched for answers and tried all the solutions but neither of them did work. I tried removing the "assets/" part

I am receiving this error even tho I think my configuration is correct:

```
successFailAudioPlayer.play("assets/audio/test.mp3", isLocal: true);
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: 0.17.0

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/audio/
    - assets/audio/test.mp3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we have to use AudioCache() instead of AudioPlayer() when we are playing audio from your assets.